# Multiple Arrays (Laravel 4)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am trying to add multiple rows to the database based on the user ID but when I submit, it only add the last row of data.

**Controller**

```
if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
    $sub1 = Input::get('sub1');
    $sub2 = Input::get('sub2');
    $sub3 = Input::get('sub3');
    $sub4 = Input::get('sub4');

    $key = Input::get('recordid');
    $req = new Results();
    foreach ($key as $id) {
        $req->st_id = $id;
        foreach ($sub1 as $s1) {
            $req->subject1 = $s1;
        }
        foreach ($sub2 as $s2) {
            $req->subject2 = $s2;
        }
        foreach ($sub3 as $s3) {
            $req->subject3 = $s3;
        }
        foreach ($sub4 as $s4) {
            $req->subject4 = $s4;
        }
        $req->save();
    }
```

My View

```
     @foreach ($data as $row)
       <tr>
         <td>{{$row->id}}
             <input name="recordid[]" id="recordid[]" value="{{ $row->id}}" type="hidden"></td>
         <td>{{$row->fname}} {{$row->lname}}</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="sub1[]" id="sub1[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="sub2[]" id="sub2[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="sub3[]" id="sub3[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="sub4[]" id="sub4[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Add marks here..."></td>
    </tr>
   @endforeach
```

...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$req  = array();
$sub1 = Input::get('sub1');
$sub2 = Input::get('sub2');
$sub3 = Input::get('sub3');
$sub4 = Input::get('sub4');
$key  = Input::get('recordid');

foreach($key as $k=>$id){
  $req[$k]['st_id']    = $id;
  $req[$k]['subject1'] = $sub1[$k];
  $req[$k]['subject2'] = $sub2[$k];
  $req[$k]['subject3'] = $sub3[$k];
  $req[$k]['subject4'] = $sub4[$k];
}

if(!empty($req)){
  DB::table('table_name')->insert($req);
}
```

Comment: I get an error for this $this->db->insert_batch('exam_result', $req); as undefined property

Comment: Kahn It is looking for a method in controller which i dont have it

Comment: i have changed $this->db->insert_batch('exam_result', $req); as DB::table('table_name')->insert($req);

Actually previous was codeigniter syntax.

Comment: @kahn I have a table with pagination. When i go to the next page and I enter the data it doesn't save all of them but only those in that page however if I return to page one of the table with pagination without pressing save, the data are there